# How to align original and filtered signal for analysis?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, filtering, signal-processing, butterworth

I used **butterworth bandpass filter** for my acceleration data. Now i want to **align/combine** both **original and smoothed signal** for **obervation/analysis**. The **issue** is i am **trying to align** but it is not working. Probably i am doing wrong. I need guidance, how can align them.
Below i am posting my output image and code i tried to use to **align** both signals. The output image i put here is consist of **original signal and filtered signal** done using **butterworth bandpass filter**. Thanks

```
delay = mean(grpdelay(B,A))
tt = Time(1:end-delay);
sn = norm(1:end-delay);

sf = Data_filtered;
sf(1:delay) = [];
plot(tt,sn)
hold on, plot(tt,sf,'-r','linewidth',1.5), hold off
title 'Gyro Filtration'
xlabel('Time (s)'), legend('Original Signal','Filtered Shifted Signal')
```

[output original and filtered signals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQiT6.png)

Comment: First of all the figure you are showing is not in line with your code, so it is difficult to see which problems you are facing. Secondary, you are using a IIR filter, which has no linear phase behavior, to average the groupdelay is not the best approach in this situation. Please read [Group and Phase delay](https://dspillustrations.com/pages/posts/misc/group-delay-and-phase-delay-example.html) to understand better the effects. Additionally it is important to know if you are only interested in a offline analysis, under this circumstances you could use a zero phase filter using `filtfilt`

Comment: Thanks for response. The code i mentioned is used to reduce delay between two signals, but this is not working my signals. The second is i did not used IIR filter, its butterworth bandpass filter and the output image i put here is the result from butterworth filter. one is original signal andother is filterd so i want to align both as can be seen that they are far from each other. i dont want to go with zero phase filter and i already used filtfilt with butterworth.

Comment: You should inform yourself better about butterworth filter, no matter if lowpass, highpass or bandpass they are IIR filter, they can be approximated by FIR however, the way they are implemented in Matlab is as IIR (which will get obvious when inspecting the variable  `A`). And you should read about the non linear phase response of those.

Comment: If you want help you should read [ask] and [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). RIght now, we dont really see what your problem is, neither can we reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you filter with filtfilt() because filfilt() has exactly zero delay at all frequencies.  It achieves this because it filters the signal forward and then backward.  The time delays on the forward pass are cancelled out by the equal but opposite delays when it goes through backward. Note that because you are filtering twice, the final attenuation at each frequency is twice as much (if measured in dB) as what you get from a single pass.  Therefore you get 6 dB attenuation at the original cutoff frequency, instead of the usual 3 dB.  For most applications, including yours I believe, this is not a problem.  If it is a problem, then you can adjust the cutoff of the initial filter definition, so that you get 3 dB attenuation at the desired cutoff after both passes.

See attached code and figure for a comparison of delay with filt() and filtfilt().  The figure shows that the raw and filtfilt() signals both transition through y=0 at the exact same time, which reflects the absence of any delay with filtfilt().  The figure also shows that the high frequency noise in the raw signal has been removed by the filter.

[image: Comparison of raw signal and output from filter() and filtfilt(), for a 4th order bandpass Butterworth with Fhpc=0.1 Hz, Flpc=5 Hz.]

If for some reason you do not want to use filtfilt(), then a very good approximation to the delay of a lowpass Butterworth filter of order n, in the passband, is

Delay = Kn/Fc (Delay in s, Fc=cutoff freq in Hz)

where Kn is a constant that depends on the filter order, n:

n=2,3,4,6,8

Kn=0.225,0.318,0.416,0.615,0.816

For more orders and the derivation, see my paper "A general solution for the time delay...", J Biomechanics (2007), https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16545388/.

```
%filterCompare.m  WCR 20210118
% Question on stack exchange
clear;

%Make an illustrative input signal
Fs=200;                     %sampling frequency (Hz)
N=800;                      %number of points
Tdur=N/Fs;                  %duration (s)
Time=(0:(N-1))/Fs;          %time vector
x=square(Time*2*pi/Tdur)...     %square wave plus high frequency ripple
    +0.2*sin(2*pi*.25*Fs*Time);

%Compute the filter coefficients
order=4;
Fhpc=0.1;                   %high pass cutoff frequency (Hz)
Flpc=5;                     %low pass cutoff frequency (Hz)
Wn1=[Fhpc,Flpc]*2/Fs;       %normalized cutoff frequencies
[b,a]=butter(order,Wn1,'bandpass');  %compute filter coefficients

%Filter the data
y1=filter(b,a,x);         %standard (forward-only) filter
y2=filtfilt(b,a,x);       %forward and backward filter

%Plot the data
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(Time,x,'r.-',Time,y1,'g.-',Time,y2,'b.-');
ylabel('Amplitude');
legend('Raw Data','filter()','filtfilt()');
grid on;
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(Time,x,'r.-',Time,y1,'g.-',Time,y2,'b.-');
xlabel('Time (s)'); ylabel('Amplitude');
legend('Raw Data','filter()','filtfilt()');
axis([.45*Tdur .55*Tdur -inf inf]);
grid on;
```

Comment: thanks for the response. i already used butterworth bandpass filter with filtfilt() and as you mentioned but still the output is same, if i use lowpass then the output is good without any delay.

Comment: If you only filtered with filtfilt(), then there is no delay between input and output signals. This is true whether the filter coefficients passed to filfilt() are Butterworth lowpass, Butterworth bandpass, or other.

Comment: but still i am getting the same output as i attached in my main post, filtered and original signals are not overlapped @rosewc

Comment: @muhamamd, The code fragment in your original post does not show how sf is computed, so I cannot comment on the possible explanation for the delay you observe between `sn` and `sf` (the raw and filtered signals).  The time scale on the figure in the original post does not allow us to see the delay between the signals.

Comment: alright, thanks for your help, i will check it again and will let you know.